# unexpected token else codecademy

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem of which I get a syntax error (Unexpected else)
Below is my code. I think it would be a "curly bracket" or semi-colon problem

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
        if (choice1 === choice2) {
            return "The result is a tie!";

        } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
            if (choice2 === "scissors") {
                return "rock swins";
            } else {
                return "paper wins";
            }
        } else if (choice1 === "paper") {
            if (choice2 === "rock") {
                return "paper wins";
            } else {
                return "scissors wins";
            } else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
                if (choice2 === "rock") {
                    return "rock wins";
                } else {
                    return "scissors wins"
                }
            }
        };
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You have if -> else -> else if. That doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks this has helped!

Answer (score 1):

Please place below code, I added one missing close bracket for last else part `else if (choice1 === "paper")`.

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";

    } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock swins";
        } else {
            return "paper wins";
        }
    } else if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "paper wins";
        } else {
            return "scissors wins";
        } else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
            if (choice2 === "rock") {
                return "rock wins";
            } else {
                return "scissors wins"
            }
        }
    } 
};
```

Let me know if there is any error remain.